# Click once issue - DTD is prohibited in this XML document

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I'm trying to deploy a WPF application using click once. When I use a local folder (publish and installation) everything is ok. When I try to deploy from a shared dropbox folder I gets the following error when I try to install:

**the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. + DTD is prohibited in this XML document**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrz5q2ybvf3xdpa/AFD3Ynd5F4rFc2KGQI4Y7WGpa?dl=0/Nouvem.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrz5q2ybvf3xdpa/AFD3Ynd5F4rFc2KGQI4Y7WGpa?dl=0/Nouvem.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrz5q2ybvf3xdpa/AFD3Ynd5F4rFc2KGQI4Y7WGpa?dl=0/Nouvem.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + DTD is prohibited in this XML document.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [27/11/2016 15:03:53] : Activation of https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrz5q2ybvf3xdpa/AF3Ynd5F4rFc2KGQI4Y7WGpa?dl=0/Nouvem.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [27/11/2016 15:03:55] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrz5q2ybvf3xdpa/AFD3Ynd5F4rFc2KGQI4Y7WGpa?dl=0/Nouvem.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Xml.XmlException
        - DTD is prohibited in this XML document.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```